# How can i ensure that the scroll events are always applied to the correct component

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a react project which has segments which it needs to scroll between.
But the segments can have content inside which can also scroll.
I want to make sure that the content inside is fully scrolled before we continue scrolling the outer content.

This is what i have so far

```
//./root

import FullHeightScrollableComponent from './components/FullHeightScrollableComponent';
import StickyHeader from './components/StickyHeader';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <StickyHeader>
        <div className="p-4">
          This is the sticky header content.
        </div>
      </StickyHeader>
      <FullHeightScrollableComponent>
        <div className="h-[150vh] bg-gray-200">
          This is the content of the first component, which is 150% of the viewport height.
        </div>
      </FullHeightScrollableComponent>

      <FullHeightScrollableComponent>
        <div className="h-[200vh] bg-gray-300">
          This is the content of the second component, which is 200% of the viewport height.
        </div>
      </FullHeightScrollableComponent>

      <FullHeightScrollableComponent>
        <div className="h-[100vh] bg-gray-400">
          This is the content of the third component, which is 100% of the viewport height.
        </div>
      </FullHeightScrollableComponent>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//./components/fullHeightScrollable

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const FullHeightScrollableComponent = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="h-screen overflow-hidden relative">
      <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full overflow-y-auto">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

FullHeightScrollableComponent.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default FullHeightScrollableComponent;
```

What i am finding is that it kind of seems to work, but it doesnt wait until the outer fullHeightSCrollables are at the top before is starts scrolling the inside. and if i dont move my mouse it seems to ignore changing whats is taking the scroll events when going back up.

is there a better way i can be doing this?
I am using react and tailwind